# pandas error: value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_play = pd.read_csv("players_stats_by_season_full_details.csv")

VC = df_play[df_play["League"] == "NBA"]
VC

VC["FT_Miss"] = VC['FTA'] - VC['FTM']
```

the error message:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 1):

`VC` is not dataframe, its a slice of the original, meaning it is just a pointer back to df_play

try;

`VC = df_play[df_play["League"] == "NBA"].copy()`